# Permanently / on-every-refresh injected javascript with selenium

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have semi-automated test with selenium webdriver (using python 3). Semi-automated means, that there are some routines, which happens every time, but also there is some user interaction with browser (possible page refreshs, redirecting, ...)

What I need is to permanently inject javascript code, which is executed with everytime page is refreshed. Selenium `execute_script` makes anonymous function wrapper and is lost with every refresh.

So is there any way to create such routine? Possible (and just fine) work-around would be to detect when browser is refreshed (and I'm not sure if it is possible) and each time inject the js again.

I don't what to create any browser extension, because the js code is only a part of a framework and is being developed. (And also I need to do this in Chrome and Firefox, which would require even more work to handle it).

Thank you for help :)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using try except functionality for the specific error thrown from Selenium when trying to execute after the page reloads.  That way you are focused on fixing the thrown error.  Then you can execute the javascript and implement recursive programming to re-execute the last statement you were attempting.

python

```
    driver.execute_script("script goes here")
    #call function at thrown exception place in script
```

Registering an event listener might allow you to catch it when it happens.  It really depends on what is to happening and where the communications of that is.  Here is the reference for that:  http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/events/WebDriverEventListener.html

Comment: I don't think this kind of exception are thrown, when page is refreshed. Selenium looks very one-way oriented, so you can control browser, but you can't retrieve user-actions (like redirecting to different page by user) - there is no exception thrown (as far as I have tested)

Selenium 1 supported something called user-extension.js, which allowed user to inject JS to the browser (not page environment) the way I want. But as far as I've researched, this feature is not supported in selenium 2 webdriver.

If I misunderstood your point, please correct me :)

Comment: Sort of, I should have been more clear...I'll edit.

Where I was coming from is that if you try to execute your Selenium code on a page that isn't the same as you expected...it doesn't work and throws an error.  So you wouldn't actually catch the page error, but the Selenium execution error because the page wasn't what you expected.  Then you execute the javascript to put it back to what you expected and recursively call the function that failed.

Is that clearer?  If not I may not be understanding what exactly this refresh is causing in which case could you put some code for clarification?

Comment: I get it now. It works - but for my purpose I'd need to check (try something) periodically, which isn't so nice, but acceptable, if no other solution is found, thanks.

Comment: Again, I don't know your code...but you could register a Selenium Event Listener that would fire.  That might be more suited for you if you want to target a specific detectable thing...you could then execute your script in there.  Edit above...